# While Loop Not Working (Function and Time.Sleep)

Tags: python, while-loop

My while loop prints nothing when it is running.

```
import os
import time

place = 10

running = True

def Write():
  j = 1
  for i in range(place - 1):
    print("-", end = "")
    j += 1
  print("a", end = "")
  for k in range(10 - j):
    print("-", end = "")

while running:
  Write()
  time.sleep(5)
  if place > 1:
    place -= 1
  os.system("clear")
```

When there is just the print and a time.sleep, the while loop works.

```
while running:
  print("Looping...")
  time.sleep(5)
```

When there is the function and a time.sleep, the code doesn't work.

```
while running:
  Write()
  time.sleep(5)
```

Please tell me how to fix this.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Add the error you get to your question or expected and received output

Comment: Your code as written works as intended on my machine - outputting `--------a-0`, waiting five seconds, then clearing and outputting `-------a--0`, etc.. There could be implementation differences between computers, though. Have you tried doing `sys.stdout.flush()` before the `os.system("clear")`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got puzzled by what you discovered, and now found a solution to this interesting behavior; you can use `flush=True` parameter to force flushing:

```py
import os
import time

place = 10

running = True

def Write():
  j = 1
  for i in range(place - 1):
    print("-", end = "")
    j += 1
  print("a", end = "", flush=True)
  for k in range(10 - j):
    print("-", end = "", flush=True)

while running:
  Write()
  time.sleep(1)
  if place > 1:
    place -= 1
  os.system("clear")
```

> Whether the output is buffered is usually determined by file, but if the flush keyword argument is true, the stream is forcibly flushed.—https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print

Alternatively, (i) putting `print()` (without `end`) at the end of `Write`, or (ii) making `Write` to return a string (not print inside the function) and printing the string outside the function (in the `while` loop) seems to work. Green Cloak Guy's solution in the comment section, i.e., `sys.stdout.flush()` works too.

It seems to me that `end=''` makes python or console reluctant to show the characters eagerly (in some cases), waiting for a line to end.